# Add a click handler that delays the browser handling the click?

Tags: jquery, click

I want to use jQuery to add a click handler to a link.  When the link is clicked by the user, jQuery needs to find a nearby panel button, trigger a click on that, wait until the panel opens (about a second) and then allow the browser to do the natural action for the link -- an anchor down the page to a location previously hidden under the collapsed panel.

```
$('a.fn').click(
  function(){
    $(this).closest(div.panel).not('.isOpen).find('div.panel a.opener').trigger('click');
    setTimeout(1000);
    return true;
  }
);
```

When clicked, the panel opens, but the browser immediately tries to anchor down the page and gets confused, stopping about halfway to the anchor target.

How do I get the browser to wait a second before executing the link action?

Comment: That depends a bit on what the default link action will be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to misunderstand how [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setTimeout) is supposed to work. I'd try something like this:

```
$('a.fn').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var href = this.href;
    $(this).closest('div.panel:not(.isOpen)').find('div.panel a.opener').trigger('click');
    setTimeout(function() {
        window.location = href; // default anchor click action
    }, 1000);
    return true;
  }
);
```

Comment: Thank you, Blazemonger.  preventDefault on the event was exactly right -- no surprise that I misunderstood how setTimeout works -- and extra points for pointing out how to save the this.href to use later.

Answer (score 1):

You should start your function with preventDefault.

```
$('a.fn').on('click', function(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();

  window.setTimeout(function() {
    $(this).closest(div.panel).not('.isOpen').find('div.panel a.opener').trigger('click');
  }, 1000);
  return true;
});
```

Comment: Thank you, Gary.  I gave the answer to Blazemonger because of the extra bit about this.href, but your answer is completely correct.  It's the preventDefault on the event that was the key that I didn't know.  Thank you!